Dominos cover $M\times N$ table, such that it's impossible to move any domino, prove that the number of empty cells is at most $\frac{MN}{5}$
A rectangular $M \times N$ board is divided into $1*1$ cells, there are also many domino pieces of size $1 * 2$, these pieces cover the board in such a way that every domino covers exactly $2$ cells, and no $2$ dominos overlap, the board is not covered completely, but it's impossible to move any dominos, prove that
(a) The number of uncovered cells is at most $\frac{1}{4} \cdot MN$.
(b) The number of uncovered cells is at most $\frac{1}{5} \cdot MN$.

As You can see here it's impossible to move any of the dominos, but the board is not fully covered.
By moving the dominos it means that instead of covering e.g. $(1, 2), (1, 3)$ after moving it covers $(1, 3), (1, 4)$ or $(2, 2), (2, 3)$
This is my solution for a:
Let's assume there exist more than $\frac{1}{4} \cdot MN$ empty cells, by the pigeonhole principle there exists a $2\times2$ such that it has at least $2$ empty cells.
it's easy to see that no matter the configuration of the dominos and empty cells in that $2\times2$, it's always possible to move a piece, which is a contradiction.
but I need help solving b, I don't even have a clue on how to approach the problem.

I think you can do it in the same way. Try 5 tiles, and try 10 tiles for the case which can't be solved by 5 tiles.

What does "it's impossible to move any dominoes" mean? I'm assuming it means that that you can't add any more dominoes precisely because you don't have any set of $1\times 2$ empty squares left.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer I've added a picture to make it more understandable.

@MaYe would you please elaborate more, for taking 5 tiles, I can't find a good shape to use the Pigeonhole principle on, if I take a straight line, the dominos may be placed in other ways, like parallel to it on the lower/upper row and perpendicular to it with 1 shared cell. which make the case forking super long.

@Behrad Try 2*2+1tile attached on the side

We first need the following two facts:

no two empty cells are adjacent;
no empty cell is on an edge of the square.

The first one you've already done (it would be part of a $2\times 2$ with two empty squares). For the second, if an empty cell is in a corner the two adjacent cells must be filled by dominoes (from the first property), and they can't both be pointing away from the corner. For an empty cell in the middle of a side it is similar.
Now note that this means every empty cell is adjacent to four dominoes. But every domino is adjacent to at most two empty cells (one along each long side). By double counting, there are at least twice as many dominoes as empty cells, and hence at least four times as many filled cells as empty cells.

a) For every dominos not at the edge of the table, there exist $6$ adjacent cells that can allow the dominos to move, the six adjacent cells plus the $2$ cells occupied by the domino make $8$ cells in total.

Since the dominos cannot move there is a maximum of $2$ uncovered adjacent cells, that is one of $2$ or $3$, and one of $5$ or $6$ (see picture), which represent $2/8=1/4$ of cells around the dominos.
For cells at the edges, a similar reasoning would work,
for cells that in a parallel orientation relative to the edge you can easily find a max of $1/6$, for the orthogonal ones you might need consider more cells, but I couldn't find a more elegant approach(for example considering $10$ cells around gives a max of $1/5$)
b) similar logic could work, just use more dominos and build up a similar picture as starter:

Hope it helps a bit to have a different perspective.
